# Blog Post Image doesn't show up when sharing to facebook

Tags: html, facebook, blogs, sharing

Please help me. I am a lowly blogger and only know enough html to be dangerous.

When sharing my Blogger posts to Facebook, the image is not shown. Why isn't my image showing when I share to Facebook?

The blog post url that I am having issues with is:
https://beauty4theash.blogspot.com/2017/12/reflecting-on-this-trip-around-sun-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Add facebook open graph meta tags
for image try that code

`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <meta preoperty='og:image' expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl'/>
</b:if>`

Answer (score 0):

Add a Social Media Meta tag On blogger.. 
 Go to blogger dashboard>> Theme >> edit html Then Paste this code above the `</head>` tag--

```
<!-- [ Social Media Meta Tag ] -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='description'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='website' property='og:type'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='&quot;Silakan kunjungi &quot; + data:blog.pageTitle + &quot; Untuk membaca postingan menarik.&quot;' property='og:description'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Hjc6_7njIRs/WIsN28cBbYI/AAAAAAAACL4/tyYVf_C1WGwqUEpqQAzvdvE0F3L7X-6pgCLcB/s125-c/Logo%2BPsd.png' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/PROFILE-LINK' property='article:author'/>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/FAN-PAGE-FACEBOOK' property='article:publisher'/>
<meta content='CODE-APPLICATION-FACEBOOK' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='CODE-ADMIN-FACEBOOK' property='fb:admins'/>
<meta content='en_US' property='og:locale'/>
<meta content='en_GB' property='og:locale:alternate'/>
<meta content='id_ID' property='og:locale:alternate'/>
<meta content='summary' name='twitter:card'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageTitle' name='twitter:title'/>
<meta content='USER-TWITTER' name='twitter:site'/>
<meta content='USER-TWITTER' name='twitter:creator'/>
```

Before Pasting Fill The Details..